What would cause "class verified rejected" in Android developing with Java, when I turn on minifyEnable?
I have a class using try-catch-finally, and it works well in debug package. But when I turn on MinifyEnable, the app crashed with class verified rejected:
java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class A: ......: [0xFB6] copy1 v28<-v1 type=Imprecise Constant: 1 cat=3.

Turn off the minifyEnable can solve the error, but it is not the real reason absolutely. Moreover, a diffusion case happens when I just remove the finally part: the code works again! I couldn't understand what happened. And what I do in the finally part be like:enter image description here
Is there anyone can help me to figure out the real reason? Thanks a lot.

The java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class gennerally occurs when the bytecode does pass the verification of Android Runtime. It can be also caused due to optimization issues.
1.Add specific Progaurd/R8 rules to keep the class unchanged at the time of minification.
-keep class com.example.Test {
    *;
}

2.Optimizing the code inside the finally block.
public class Test {

    public Result test() {
        Result result = new Result();
        int b = 0;
        try {

            b = 1;
            return result;
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            b = 2;
            return result;
        } 
        finally {

            setResultA(result, b);  //Some optimization here.
        }
    }

    private void setResultA(Result result, int value) {
        result.a = value;
    }

    class Result {
        int a;
    }
}

Hope this helps

Thanks a lot. Optimazing the finally block does helps, but I don't understand how it works. Maybe I need to learn about the fundations of compile and minify.

Minifiers like ProGuard or R8 may sometimes generate incorrect bytecode when complex control flows (like try-catch-finally) are involved. This can lead to verification errors. If it helped please mark the answer as acepted.
